# Why can't I set state in the constructor of a component?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've only got a single `this.setState` call in my whole code, and that's in the constructor, yet I'm getting `setState` errors.

I've reduced it to the following code for clarity:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.setState({
       hello: 'nothing'
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The error is as follows:
[image]

> `proxyConsole.js:56` Warning: `setState(...)`: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called `setState()` on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the `App` component.

Why is this happening and how can I set the state in the constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you set initial state when the component is being constructed, set `this.state` directly, do not use `this.setState`. `setState` can only be used when the component has been mounted, and in the constructor the component has *not* been mounted -- thus set the state directly. Per [the React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#constructor):

> **`constructor()`**
>
> `constructor(props)`
>
> **The constructor for a React component is called before it is mounted.** [...]
>
> The constructor is the right place to initialize state. If you don't initialize state and you don't bind methods, you don't need to implement a constructor for your React component.

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
   hello: 'nothing'
  };
}
```

Per [the React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly):

> The only place where you can assign `this.state` is the constructor.

Comment: That is probably the silliest error I could have ever made. Sorry, it's been a while since I Reacted, but thank you. I'll leave this up incase someone else runs into this problem.